# php raspberry pi trying to change pi date

Tags: php, apache, date, raspberry-pi, sudo

have a PHP script here:

```
echo shell_exec('sudo date --set="15 NOV 2015 12:43:10"');
echo "<br>";
echo date("d m Y H:i:s");
```

Ive tried with sudo and without and the date does not change on the pi

Any Idea's?

Thanks
likdaboo

Comment: Did you check the file permissions?

Comment: Just changed them to 777 and still no luck

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo date -s "Wed Dec 31 12:31:26 UTC 2014"`?

Comment: I don't think sudo would work from a php script. you maybe better with a bash script that is called from PHP or that is run on a cron job

Comment: Make that `echo shell_exec('sudo date --set="15 NOV 2015 12:43:10" 2>&1');` to capture any errors.  I suspect that `sudo` is not properly set up for this.

Comment: so a php script is able to run a bash script? ill give that ago, and is it not possible to add the php user to the sudoers file?

Comment: okay i ran that @legoscia and got this: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh okay figured it out

had to add the PHP user to the sudoers

the php user is called www-data

I got the username from doing this:

```
echo shell_exec("whoami");
```

Thanks all